# Get access to specific API using oauth requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, google-colaboratory

I have been trying to get access to this API https://api.linkdex.com/application.wadl.html but the response code has been 401 :(

```
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1

url = 'https://api.linkdex.com/v1/projects/list'
auth = OAuth1('keyxxxxxxxxx', 'secretxxxxxxx',
                  'USER_OAUTH_TOKEN', 'USER_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET')

requests.get(url, auth=auth)
```

Comment: It sounds as if the thing you're trying to access requires authentication and you're not providing any means to authenticate your request. Do you have have an API key?

Comment: share your code

Comment: add the key and secret!

Answer (score 0):

This works in Python 3. Checked now.

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get('https://api.linkdex.com/application.wadl.html')
<Response [200]>
```

[image: pic]

In the docs it says:

> The OAuth signing process also generates a timestamp and unique
>   request id.
>   The Linkdex API will validate the signed request,
>   including the timestamp and unique id, before allowing access to the
>   requested resource.
>   An HTTP 401 Unauthorized response will be returned
>   if access to the resource is not permitted.

Therefore, maybe your request (key, secret) is not a valid one.

Comment: I believe you're just making a request to the documentation there, not an actual resource/endpoint of the API.

Comment: IDK but thats what he asked for

Comment: it does but not for authentication

Comment: u need the secret.